# Rest assured - log status code if validation is incorrect

Tags: assert, rest-assured

I just started with the Rest assured for API validation and hit the problem how to log (report) status code or body from the response in case that validation is not correct.
This code:

`req.log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.STATUS).expect().statusCode(404).when().get();`

just prints

> FAILED: testStatusNotFoundu
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: STATUS is not a valid LogDetail for a request.

If it is used this code
`req.log().ifValidationFails().expect().statusCode(404).when().get();`
then it prints

> FAILED: testStatusNotFoundu
>   java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
>   Expected status code <404> doesn't match actual status code <200>.

I would like to see the status code printed as well + the response body.
Please can anybody share a bit knowledge?

Comment: I was able to print body or status code in case that test case passes. 
req.expect().statusCode(200).when().get().then().log().body();
But how to get it printed in case of the validation fails?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my needs by using this code.

```
req.given().when().get().then().log().ifValidationFails().statusCode(200);
```